# Array push still using previous reference?

Tags: javascript

I have following code:

```
var students = [];
for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    var student = {};
    student = classes[i].student;
    student.teacher = classes[i].teacher;
    students.push(student);
}
```

Somehow the students will print same object for all its contents, although I have put `var student = {};` inside the loop, thus it must not refer to same reference.

Anyone has idea why this happens?

Comment: Note that your `var student = {};` assignment immediately gets invalidated by the `student = classes[i].student;` assignment. The result of those two lines if identical to running the single assignment `var student = classes[i].student;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put `student = {}` inside the loop, then on the line immediately following that one you overwrote that by assigning `student = classes[i].student`.

If the intention is to make a copy of whatever `classes[i].student` is you can use the [`Object.assign()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
var student = Object.assign({}, classes[i].student);
```

In context:

```
var students = [];
for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    var student = Object.assign({}, classes[i].student);
    student.teacher = classes[i].teacher;
    students.push(student);
}
```

(Note that `Object.assign()` doesn't do a deep copy - I'm not sure if that matters because you haven't shown what the `classes` array structure is.)

You could also use the [`.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of an explicit `for` loop:

```
var students = classes.map(function(c) {
  var student = Object.assign({}, c.student);
  student.teacher = c.teacher;
  return student;
});
```

Comment: Actually I want to put student object to be the first level. If I use this code `student: classes[i].student`, it will be nested object.

Comment: I thought if I use `student = classes[i].student, it should refer to different object instead?

Comment: I've updated my answer with code that makes a copy of the `classes[i].student` object. Regarding your original `student = classes[i].student`, that assigns the `student` variable to refer to the same object that `classes[i].student` refers to.

Comment: Yeah many thanks for your help! But I thought for each `classes[i].student` will have different reference, thus I thought `student = classes[i].student` should be working..

Comment: No, for objects `=` makes another reference to the existing object.

Comment: I see.. Thanks for your explanation!